# How to use tor on Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk, tor

I wanted to use Android SDK Manager on Windows 8.1 but due to sanctions on Iran I can't use it properly. So I need tor for that but in its Proxy settings, it only have HTTP but Tor use socks5. Have can I use Android SDK Manager without limit?

Comment: Would you please share your solution with us??

Answer (score 2):

In cmd:

```
sdkmanager.bat --proxy=socks --proxy_host=127.0.0.1 --proxy_port=9050 "platforms;android-25"
```

or in Android Studio: File->Settings->Appearance & Behaviour/System Settings/HTTP Proxy - Manual proxy configuration: SOCKS...

Answer (score 1):

Use Tor Browser.
when your tor browser is connected :

1.Open Menu ->Select Options -> Advanced -> Network -> Connection Setting

then you'll see your Tor socks's name and port.

2.Copy Sock's `Host : Ip` for example `127.0.0.1:9150`

leave tor browser open

4.Go to Android Studio ->Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy

5.in the right section Select Manual Proxy Configuration and Socks

6.Fill Host and Port fields with Tor Host and Port

7.OK!!!

if Android Studio asked for HTTP settings leave it empty.

now you can update your SDK and Download Dependencies with Gradle :)

Comment: The default Tor port for incoming connections locally would be 9050 not 9150 that seems like a typo

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Do this actions:

1. do not change android studio proxy setting (use no proxy)
2. start tor browser
3. in terminal use this command:

   $ torsocks -P 9150 /YOUR PATH/studio.sh

it's work bot it's too Slowly

Answer (score 0):

Tor uses Socks4a, not Socks5. So you need a client that implements Socks4a. I resolved this by implementing my own Socket factories for apache httpComponents library. You can check it [here](https://github.com/jehy/Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library).